# European Football Datasets PAST and Current Season

Tags: data-request, sports, football

I've been trying to find player stats datasets but couldn't find one that includes goals scored, assists, etc. Does anybody know any site that provides such data for free or If I could get the last 20-30 years of European leagues data with match scores and also who scored in that game, something like this:

```
Barca 2 - 1 Sevilla

[Messi'70,Suarez'80 : Navas'23]
```

Something like this would be Awesome!! .... There are some that provide match scores like this but do not list the player names that scored in the match.
I want data to not only have names of scorers but also detailed info like possession stats, HT score, cards received, shots on target, saves and other stats. Even if you know datasets like this of just 5-6 years. please do mention.

Your little help will mean a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the European Soccer Database https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer